# Python ENV file overwritten by PHP ENV

Tags: php, python, shell, environment-variables

I'm working with PHP and a Laravel framework, and I use .env to set my environment variables. I then call python scripts from my PHP environment, and return the result to PHP. My problem is, the default `os.environ` set in Python is being overridden by my PHP's environment.

My code (an example):

```
<?php
//Setting up the laravel environment and loading in the $_ENV variable
exec('python script.py');
```

and then my python:

```
print os.environ
```

`print os.environ` will return all of my environment variables set during the PHP environment setup. All of the default environment variables, such as PATH, are either not set or overridden by the new env.

It took me a while to diagnose the problem. However, with my limited knowledge of python, how to solve it is proving problematic. Is there a way I can reinitialize the python environment without affecting the PHP environment, and vice versa? Basically I need both processes to be separate from one another environment-wise, or I need to set the python environment, then update it with the old values before returning to PHP.

If anybody knows how to go about that you'd be a lifesaver.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The child processes inherit the environment variables from their parent processes on startup. No changes in the child process' environment are ever propagated to the parent process.

In your case, the python script is the child process; it inherits the environment from the php script; now you are free to do any changes to `os.environ` and these wouldn't affect the php process at all, for example prepend a new path in the beginning of the `PATH` environment variable

```
os.environ['PATH'] = '/home/foo/bar/bin:' + os.environ['PATH']
```

---

As for the PHP, the changes in `$_ENV` should not be inherited by child processes, only the ones explicitly set with `putenv` should be inherited by children.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Do you have any idea how I might be able to retrieve the default python environment / reinitialize that environment?

Comment: @JamesSpence There is no "default python environment". Environments *always* come from the parent process. You can force a "disowned" environment with the `env` command if that's what you want though.

Comment: @EtanReisner what is a "disowned" environment? Any chance you could push me a link in the right direction?

Comment: @JamesSpence `man env`. In this sense "disowned" means "divorced from the environment of the running process". `env` inserts itself between the parent and child process and scrubs the environment as clean as you tell it to (and can also inject environment variables you tell it to) so you get a "pristine" environment for the child.

Comment: @EtanReisner Thanks for the reference. So would I modify the PHP script to look something like `env && python script.py`?

Comment: @JamesSpence `env -i python script.py` to start with an "empty environment" which may or may not be what you want exactly but at least gives you a clean start.